# Unable to use apt in WSL Ubuntu due to security issues

Tags: apt, updates, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ssl, certificates

I'm trying to install `make` on a WSL instance in my Windows machine. So I tried the following command:

`sudo apt install make`

After entering my credentials, and pressing enter, I got the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  make-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  make
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 180 kB of archives.
After this operation, 426 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 make amd64 4.3-4.1build1
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 make amd64 4.3-4.1build1
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 make amd64 4.3-4.1build1
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 make amd64 4.3-4.1build1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/make-dfsg/make_4.3-4.1build1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I am also aware that on my local machine there is a rather strict security system related to fetching certificates. Often while installing Python packages using pip I will have to use things like `--trusted-host` or other ways to bypass certification or SSL.

I'm not sure whether these two things are related, but running the same `apt` command with `--allow-unauthenticated` did not make any difference. Running `apt-get update` resulted in the following:

```
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Are you using WSL or WSL2? This appears to be a DNS issue rather than anything to do with trust / certificates

Comment: `wsl -v` shows WSL version 1.1.3.0. I've tried it on multiple reliable connections from my workplace and from home, hence why I'm willing to rule out DNS issues. I'm able to browse through the web with no issues (except for the few websites blocked by our IT department)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your WSL instance is encountering difficulties in resolving package sources, potentially due to DNS issues. I had a similar problem, and the following steps helped me resolve it:

Check if the file **/etc/resolv.conf** exists and contains valid DNS servers. You can create the file and set a DNS server with the following commands:

```
touch /etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

This creates the file and sets Google's DNS server (8.8.8.8) as the nameserver. You can use alternative DNS servers if needed.

Retry installing the package:

```
sudo apt install make
```

This should resolve the issue. In my case, this step alone was sufficient.